# Python calculator calculate without fraction

Tags: python, calculator

I'm trying to write a script that will return you all the prime numbers till the number that you entered, and the problem is that if you ask python how much it's `17/2`, it will answer 8, also with `27/2` it will answer 13, how do I fix it ?

I tried `float()` but it doesn't work.

Edit: The script that I wrote, till now:

```
array=[2,3,5,7]
num=int(raw_input("Please enter a number higher then 8:    ex:12\n")) 
for i in range(8,num): 
    b=float(i)
    if b%2.0 and b%3.0 and b%4.0 and b%5.0 and b%6.0 and b%7.0 and b&8.0 and b%9.0!=0:    
        array.append(b)
        print array
```

Comment: Which calculator gives you `17/2=9` and `27/2=14`?

Comment: The basic one, I just write 17/2 in the and it print 9.

Comment: yea it print 8, my mistake.

Comment: And, don't compare like that with hard-coding values. Rather use a loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

```
17 / 2.0 or 

17.0 / 2
```

Comment: It worked, thank you mate !, but isn't there any other way? to write 12/7 and it will answer 8.5 ? with 12.0/7

Comment: Also correct answers have to mark as right answer and upvoted.

Comment: I need to wait 11min to makr an answer as "Currect anaswer"

Comment: @user2393267 Upvote isn't a given for a correct answer: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/269931/3714940

Comment: I need total 15 reputation to upvote, that means that I still can't do it.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use integers you can use:

```
from __future__ import division
a = 4
b = 6
c = a / b
print c
```

Outputs:

```
0.66666666666666663
```

Answer (score 0):

You want this I guess

```
num = 25

primeList=[]
for val in range(2,num):
    if not any(val%i==0 for i in primeList):
        primeList.append(val)

print primeList
```

for **num=25**, it outputs:(python 2.7.6)

```
[2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23]
```

for **num=100**, it outputs:

```
[2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29, 31, 37, 41, 43, 47, 53, 59, 61,  
 67, 71, 73, 79, 83, 89, 97]
```

Comment: Copied and tried it, got : ./Ex7.py: line 1: num: command not found
./Ex7.py: line 3: syntax error near unexpected token `('
./Ex7.py: line 3: `for val in range(2,num):'

Comment: What have you got? I run it successfully.

Comment: and if I'm not wrong, val%i==0 is used to check if the number is odd or even, not prime.

Comment: `val%i==0` calculates if  Remainder is 0 , when you divide val with i. In that case, I have compared each number with every number of primeList. If there is no number in the primeList which can divide the number (i) with remainer 0, the number is prime, otherwise not.

Comment: But in the script you didn't define what is i

Comment: `if not any(val%i==0 for i in primeList):`, look the line carefully before telling that I haven't defined `i`. By the way, I have tested the code and this is a successfully run code with expected output. So, nothing wrong with the code.Thanks

Comment: As you can understand from my question and my scrip, I knew to python, I just don't understand how "if not any(val%i==0 for i in primeList):" define "i". i doesn't need to be defined before that lane ?